# How to initialize a global pointer when embedding Python in C using Swig?

Tags: python, c, pointers, embed, swig

I have a "router like" project in c, processing different packets. It is already working fine.
Now I'm extending it to process some new packets in python. I used Swig to wrap some of the existing functions(like send packet to lower layer).

The problems occurs when I'm evoking the wrapped functions:

```
//router.c
Queue_t *queue;
....
//processPkt.c
int process_new_in_c(pkt)
{
    if(pkt.new == True)
        Py_init();
        init_MyModule();
        import_Module(process.py);
        process_new_in_py(pkt);            
        Py_finalize();
     ....
}

//processNew.py
def process_new_in_py(pkt)
    ...
    MyModule.sendToLowerLayer(pkt);

//lowerlayer.c->wrapped into MyModule
int sendToLowerLayer(pkt)
{
    ...
    sendToQueue(queque, pkt);
}
```

the queue is a buffer for out going packet, which is initialized when the program is up.

However when I called wrapped function `MyModule.sendToLowerLayer(queue, pkt)` the program crashes. I ensured that it received a Null pointer of queue when it should be initialized already.

1. queue is defined in C before `process_new_in_c` is called
2. I only exposed `sendToLowerLayer()` to Python which does not require a queue args. But it called `sendToQueue()`  later
3. C->Py->wrapped C where in wrapped C, the global queue became a null pointer.

This problem is driving me crazy T_T

my .i file is :

```
%module MyModule
%inline% {
    #include ...
    int sendToLowerLayer(pkt);
%}
```

Sorry for the lazy code, I am just afraid that the origin code is too much to read.

I have a `process_new_in_c` calling a `process_new_in_py`, and in the python function I am calling a wrapped C function `send_to_lower_layer`, the `queue` is declared and initialized in C already, but when I'm calling the wrapped function `send_to_lower_layer` the `queue` seems never initialized.

the problem I think it could be:
When calling the `init_MyModule()` it declared a `fake global variable` like : `MyModule.queue` which is never initialized.
so when the code executes to the `sendToQueue(queue, pkt)` it is actually calling with `MyModule.queue` instead of queue(have a valid value inside the C part)

Comment: In C, global variables that are not otherwise initialized at their declaration are zero initialized. That means that a global variable that is a pointer will be initialized to point to `NULL`. If you haven't made the pointer point to something else, then you're dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: But before the pointer is called in the wrapped function , it already pointed to some where else. and from the C side it is not 'NULL' any more. But no matter how it changes at C side, when calling the wrapped function, the change seems not been passed thought it is a global pointer.

Comment: I just tried an global 'int a', the change will stay if I declared it and modify it through MyModule.cvar.a   but when it comes to an pointer..I have no idea what I should do T-T

Comment: Please take another look at what you posted, it is rather messed up. Like you have a C function `process_new_in_c` calling a python function `process_new_in_py`, is that really the case?

Comment: Yes, I have a `process_new_in_c` calling a `process_new_in_py`, and in the python function I am calling a wrapped C function `send_to_lower_layer`, the `queue` is declared and initialized in C already, but when I'm calling the wrapped function `send_to_lower_layer` the `queue` seems never initialized. (i add this to the question description, sorry for the mess=.=)